# C++ read and write multiple objects

Tags: c++, vector, ofstream, instances

I'm learning C++ and i'm creating a simple project for practice. Now i want to save multiple instances of the same class that are stored in a vector. I tried to save the whole vector in a binary file using ofstream, but the result was disappointing... What is the easiest way to save multiple instances and read them back??

Comment: google:// serialization in C++

Comment: You should read this: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/serialization.html

Comment: Perhaps Boost fits your needs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: PicklingTools is another solution: http://www.picklingtools.com